# How can I simplify adding multiple countifs in excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

In this specific case I want to count how many times a set of variables combines in the same line, over 5 different columns, using excel, without macros.

So far I'm using multiple `=COUNTIFS()`, but this feels cumbersome and bruteforced.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to solve this problem?

Example data in **A1**

| Modality wk 1 | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mod1 | John | Karen | John | Joe | Lizzie |
| Mod2 | Karen | Lizzie | Karen | John | John |

| Modality wk 2 | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mod1 | Joe | Karen | John | Karen | Lizzie |
| Mod2 | Karen | Joe | Karen | Karen | John |

To create a table like this, located in **A10**

| Names | Mod1 | Mod2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3 | 3 |
| Karen | 3 | 5 |
| Lizzie | 2 | 1 |
| Joe | 2 | 1 |

I'd have to use a formula like this in **B11** and drag to fill the columns and rows *(the **$** were put to help with the drag and drop)*:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,B$10,$C$1:$C$6,$A11)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,B$10,$D$1:$D$6,$A11)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,B$10,$F$1:$F$6,$A11)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,B$10,$E$1:$E$6,$A11)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,B$10,$B$1:$B$6,$A11)
```

Actual data example: [Example data.xls](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ahqnvy56ysrxyUB3xX82aLnSOlRi?e=c451SF)

Comment: Can you please edit your post and translate what "alpha", "beta" and columns 1, 2, 3 etc relate to in your data sample? I find it very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
 =SUM(($B$2:$F$7=$A11)*($A$2:$A$7=B$10))
```

[image]

If you have `LAMBDA()` function to your excel then can try this dynamic approach. No need to drag down, it will spill results automatically. Just drag across right.

```
=BYROW($A$11:$A$14,LAMBDA(x,SUM(($B$2:$F$7=x)*($A$2:$A$7=B10))))
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to forget that with DA functions Sum() can now do what Sumproduct() was needed for in the past. Nice.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem elegantly on the example data, but for some reason returns 0 on my original data. I guess I'll have to read some more...

Comment: @DeLiK Should work. Let us know if need help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm over-simplifying, but on the other hand, maybe you are over-complicating. The result is exactly what you specified.

In B12, copy across and down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$F$6=$A12)*($A$2:$A$6=B$11))
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you, it's also a possible solution, but again when applied to the main data, returns 0. I'l have to scratch my head some more

Comment: Can you post a data sample that reflects your actual data structure, then? What is different in your real data? Are the name values in the cells exactly the same?

Comment: Edited post with link to sample data

Comment: All sorted, Thank you